# Node middleware TS in return

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, class

i made this middleware and tryied to find what i put in the place of "any", but i dont found the answer, anyone know what type i can set in return of this function?

```
 verifyBodyFigure(
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction
  ): Response | any {
    const { data } = req.body;

    try {
      figureBodySchema.parse(data);
    } catch (err) {
      if (err instanceof ZodError) {
        const error = new FormatError();
        return res.status(400).json(error.convertError(err));
      }
    }
    next();
  }
```

it returns a Response from express, or go to next middleware, if i set without any, its says:
Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.ts(2366)

maybe void?

Comment: Yes, void will work in the case of no return

Comment: but theres another best solution?